# unbound method delete() must be called with Subscription instance as first argument (Stripe API)

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm working with Stripe API to cancel a subscription using the subscription ID. In all the tests, the `stripe.Subscription.delete` works fine but in some (very few) cases, it just gives this error `unbound method delete() must be called with Subscription instance as the first argument`.

First I thought that the Stripe object wasn't defined correctly but in the same function, I'm making another Stripe API call to get the subscription list (`stripe.Subscription.list`). This works every time.

This is a bit confusing scenario so any help would be great.

```
try:
    sub_id = <sub_id from the API call>
    logging.info('sub_id = %s', sub_id)
    logging.info('isinstance(sub_id, unicode) = %s', isinstance(sub_id, unicode))
                
    if isinstance(sub_id, unicode):
        sub_id = sub_id.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        logging.info('sub_id is unicode. Converting to ascii = %s', sub_id)
    else:
        logging.info('sub_id is _not_ a unicode string')
except Exception as e:
    subject_str = 'hit exception when canceling subcription in stripe. Error = %s'%e
    logging.error(subject_str)
            
    stripe.Subscription.delete(sub_id)
    return True
```

Added try-except just to make sure I'm always passing string argument.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, it's happening because the Subscription ID is for a sub that doesn't exist.  You might want to file this as an issue in Github - along with details of the version you're using - as there may be something odd going on under the hood.  https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, I'll try testing it around the missing subscription ID.